# SQL Case Statement with parameters

Tags: sql-server, parameters, case

I have the following SQL which will give me a job description and department output:

```
declare @JOB_DESC nvarchar (50)
declare @DEPARTMENT nvarchar (50)
declare @Initials nvarchar (50)

select case 
@Initials = 'XBF' then (@JOB_DESC = 'Partner', @DEPARTMENT = '_Banking and Finance'),
@Initials = 'XMA' then (@JOB_DESC = 'Partner', @DEPARTMENT = '_Disputes'),

else

SELECT @JOB_DESC = u.NAME, @DEPARTMENT = u.PracticeAreaName
FROM USERS u where u.USERID = @Initials

select @JOB_DESC
select @DEPARTMENT
```

So I basically want to force the job description and department if the initials are XBF or XMA, but otherwise I want to get my output from the general users table, but this is not working for me and I'm struggling to find the right SQL online.  Management Studio is saying 'Incorrect Syntax near '='' in reference to the first '=' in the case statement.... Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this with an `IF...ELSE` - there is nothing that a `CASE` statement makes easier.

```
IF @Initials = 'XBF'
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Partner' AS JOB_DESC, '_Banking and Finance' AS DEPARTMENT
END
ELSE IF @Initials = 'XMA'
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Partner' AS JOB_DESC, '_Disputes' AS DEPARTMENT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT u.NAME AS JOB_DESC, u.PracticeAreaName AS DEPARTMENT
    FROM USERS u where u.USERID = @Initials
END
```

Similar code if you wanted them as variables instead

```
declare @JOB_DESC nvarchar (50)
declare @DEPARTMENT nvarchar (50)

IF @Initials = 'XBF'
BEGIN
    SELECT @JOB_DESC = 'Partner', @DEPARTMENT = '_Banking and Finance'
END
ELSE IF @Initials = 'XMA'
BEGIN
    SELECT @JOB_DESC = 'Partner', @DEPARTMENT = '_Disputes' 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @JOB_DESC = u.NAME, @DEPARTMENT = u.PracticeAreaName 
    FROM USERS u where u.USERID = @Initials
END

select @JOB_DESC
select @DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: Legend! I could kiss you!  Thanks - Lydia.

Comment: Glad I could help, but hold the kissing :|